# Is there any sequence of functions containing functions growing slower than any smooth function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

The function

$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
      e^{-\frac{1}{x}} & x > 0 \\
      0 & x\leq 0 \\
   \end{cases}$

is a smooth function which grows, at $0$, slower than any function of the form $x^n$.

My question is, does there exist a sequence of functions $(f_n)$, infinitely differentiable at $0$ and with $f_n(0)=0$ and $f_n(x)\neq 0$ when $x\neq 0$ for all $n$, with the following property?

> For any function $f$ infinitely differentiable at 0 where $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)\neq 0$ when $x\neq 0$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f_n(x)}{f(x)}=0$.

Or is there no such sequence of functions, i.e. for any sequence of functions does there exist a function which grows more slowly than all the functions in the sequence?

Comment: Didn't you mean $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{f_n(x)}{f(x)}=0$ and shouldn't there be some restrictions on $f$ to allow the division? E.g., $x^2$ is slower growing than $x$ at $x=0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{x^2}{x}=0$. ... Or maybe I misunderstood the core topic of the question.

Comment: @Tobias You’re right, I edited the question.

Comment: With the current formulation of the question there is such a sequence, i.e., $f_n(x):=0$ for all admissible $x$ and $n$. That means you need some more restrictions on $f_n$.

Comment: @Tobias OK, what about this?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I improved my answer to a better result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such $C^\infty$ function. To prove this, let  $f_n$ satisfy the conditions you specify. WLOG, we can assume all $f_n>0$ on $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}.$ If that is not true, go to the functions $f_n^2.$ We will construct an even $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R),$ positive on $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$ and strictly increasing on $[0,\infty),$ such that for every $n,$

$$\tag 1\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f_n(x)}{f(x)}=\infty.$$

For any $g\in C^l(\mathbb R),$ define

$$\|g\|_l = \sum_{j=0}^{l}\sup_{\mathbb R} |D^jg|.$$

If $g_k\in C^\infty(\mathbb R), k = 1,2,\dots,$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \|g_k\|_l <\infty$ for each $l,$ then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} g_k \in C^\infty(\mathbb R).$ Furthermore, for each $l,$

$$D^l\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} g_k\right ) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} D^lg_k.$$

Choose a sequence $a_1>a_2 > \cdots \to 0.$ For each $k,$ set $E_k=\{x:a_{k+1}\le |x|\le a_k\}$ and define $m_k$ to be the smallest of the numbers

$$\min_{E_k} f_1,\min_{E_k} f_2,\dots,\min_{E_k} f_k.$$

Now choose a positive sequence $c_k\to 0$ such that $c_km_k$ strictly decreases to $0.$

For each $k$ we can choose $g_k\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ with $g_k>0$ on $(a_{k+1},a_k)$ and $g_k=0$ elsewhere. By multiplying by small enough positive constants we can also require

$$\|g_k\|_k < 1/2^k \text { and } \int_{a_{k+1}}^{a_k} g_k < c_km_k - c_{k+1}m_{k+1}.$$

We then define

$$g = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}g_k.$$

This $g\in C^\infty(\mathbb R).$

Finally we get to define $f$ (almost): Define

$$f(x) = \int_0^x g,\,\, x\in \mathbb R.$$

Then $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ and $f$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\infty).$ Fix $n.$ Claim: If $x\in [a_{k+1},a_k]$ and $k\ge n,$ then

$$\tag 2\frac{f_n(x)}{f(x)} \ge \frac{1}{c_k}.$$

Since $c_k\to 0^+,$ $(2)$ proves $(1),$ at least as $x\to 0^+.$ To prove $(2),$ note $f(x)\le f(a_k).$ Now

$$f(a_k) = \int_0^{a_k} g =\sum_{j=k}^{\infty}\int_{a_{j+1}}^{a_j} g_j < \sum_{j=k}^{\infty}(c_jm_j - c_{j+1}m_{j+1}) = c_km_k.$$

So

$$\frac{f_n(x)}{f(x)}\ge \frac{f_n(x)}{f(a_k)} > \frac{m_k}{c_km_k}=\frac{1}{c_k},$$

proving $(2).$

We're done except for a minor detail. This $f=0$ on $(-\infty,0].$ All we need to do is redefine $f$ for $x\le 0$ by setting $f(x)=f(-x).$ Because all $D^lf(0)=0$ for the original $f,$ the redefined $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R ).$ Since the $m_k$ took into account the behavior of the $f_n$ to the left of $0,$ we have our counterexample as claimed.

Comment: I think we can do better: There should exist $f$ with

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f_n(x)}{f(x)}=\infty$$

for each $n.$ I'll look into this.

Comment: Wow, your edit makes this result even more impressive.  This means that the order structure of the set of functions ordered according to how fast or slow they grow has a very interesting structure.  It constitutes an ordered set where every countable subset has an upper bound.  It may be order-isomorphic to the Long Line or something.  I think I’ll post a question on this.

Comment: I just posted a follow-up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2877922/71829

Answer (score 1):

There is no such sequence at least if we don't insist on the requirement that $f$ is infinitely often differentiable.

Assume the contrary.

Construct $a_n$ with $\emptyset\neq\left(-a_n,a_n\right)\subseteq f_n^{-1}\left(\left(-\frac1n,\frac1n\right)\right)$ and $a_{n+1}\leq \frac{a_{n}}2$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$. (Possible since the $f_n$ are continuous at $0$.)

Define $f(x) := f_n(x)$ for $x\in (-a_{n},a_{n})\setminus(-a_{n+1},a_{n+1})$.

Now assume $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f_n(x)}{f(x)}=0$ for $n\geq N$. Then we have some $\delta>0$ such that $\left|\frac{f_n(x)}{f(x)}\right|< 0.5$ for all $x\in(-\delta,\delta)$ and $n\geq N$. But we also have some $n\geq N$ with $(-a_{n},a_{n})\subset (-\delta,\delta)$ and $\frac{f_n(x)}{f(x)}=1$ for $x\in(-a_n,a_n)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: How do you know that $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$?

Comment: @PhoemueX Nice catch. We might even have $f(x)=1$ for $x\neq 0$ if each of the $f_n$ only gets $\neq 1$ for $x\in\left(0,\frac1{2(n+1)}\right)$:-). So some more work is required... I knew it couldn't be that simple.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Sorry, I don't have too much time. So I relaxed the strong differentiability conditions for $f$ to make the proof simple. I think it also shows in that form what you essentially wanted to see. Maybe someone other shows the statement for differentiable $f$ and you can accept his answer.

Comment: @PhoemueX I dealt with your argument. Hope the proof for the relaxed statement (without differentiability requirement for $f$) is correct now. (Thanks again for your comment.)

Comment: I unaccepted your answer because $f$ being infinitely differentiable at $0$ is actually critically important for my purposes.  (My motivation for asking this question is as part of finding some way to find out if a point is a local maximum or minimum if the higher-order derivative test fails.)

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Unaccepting this answer is perfectly fine with me. Thanks for the info. Hopefully my answer helps somebody else with giving an answer for the infinitely often differentiable case. Maybe some weighting of the functions $f_n$ with $\exp(-1/x)$ in combination with the already used pre-images helps. That would probably be my next attempt.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some typos in your question. We can simply put, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f_{n}(x)=1$.
Then, for any $f$ such that $f'(0)$ exists and $f(0)=0$, we automatically have: For each $n$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x)}{f_{n}(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)=0$
because $f$ is continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: I guess the OP wants $f_n (0)=0$ for all $n$ (although he didn't write it).

Comment: @PhoemueX Yeah, I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
$$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
      e^{-\frac{1}{x^n}} & x > 0 \\
      0 & x\leq 0 \\
   \end{cases}$$
for $n=1,2,3,4,\ldots$ as a slower and slower growing sequence.

Comment: Is there no smooth function that grows slower than all the functions in that sequence?  Can you prove that?

Comment: These things always have a next step.  The next I would think of is $$e^{-\frac 1{e^{-\frac 1x}}}$$ but I am not sure it works.

Comment: So is there no sequence of functions such that no function grows slower than them all?

Comment: I don't believe so

Comment: If you can prove that there’s no such sequence that would answer my question.

Comment: Given any slow growing function $f(x)$, we know $(f(x))^2$ will grow more slowly near $0$

Comment: Yes, but the statements “For every function there is a slower growing function.” and “There exists a sequence of functions such that no function grows slower than all the functions in the sequence.” are perfectly consistent with one another.