# What is the order type of the set of smooth functions ordered by growth rate?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, order-theory, ordinals, well-orders

Let $X$ be the set of functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ infinitely differentiable at $0$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)>0$ when $x\neq 0$.  Now let us define a partial order $\preceq$ on $X$ by saying that $f\preceq g$ if $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f}{g}=0$.  (That is, if $f$ grows infinitely slower than $g$.)  My question is, what is the order type of a maximal total suborder (AKA a maximal chain) of $X$ under $\preceq$?

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2875597/71829) shows that any countable subset of $X$ has a lower bound. And I assume it can be similarly shown that any countable subset has an upper bound.  So what kind of ordered set would a maximal total suborder of $X$ be order-isomorphic to?  Would it be order isomorphic to $\omega_1^{*}+\omega_1$, or to the [Long Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)), or what?

Comment: With "differentiable at $0$" you mean in a neighborhood of $0$?

Comment: Comment: A maximal totally ordered subset would not be a well order. Between any two functions $f\preceq g$ there is always another $h$ such that $f\preceq h\preceq g$. See [[[here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/growth.pdf#page=7)]]. The link talks about sequences, but using Whitney extension theorem you can do the same work with smooth functions. So, you should be looking at dense order types.

Comment: OK, so is it order-isomorphic to the Long Line? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)

Comment: @amsmath I meant what I said, infinitely differentiable at the point $0$.

Comment: I don't like your tone. Especially since you don't seem to understand. "inifinitely differentiable" in one point is not defined. Not even "twice differentiable" because for $f''(0)$ you need $f'$ to be defined in a nbh of zero.

Comment: @amsmath I’m sorry, I didn’t mean to sound rude.  In any case, what’s wrong with the definition “$f^{(n)}(0)$ exists for all $n$”?

Comment: Ok, you're forgiven. ;o) How would you define $f''(0)$ without having $f'(x)$ for $x\neq 0$?

Comment: @amsmath Well, I agree that if a function is infinitely differentiable at a point then each of its nth derivatives exists on some open interval containing that point.  (Although I’m not sure whether there must exist a single open interval on which all the nth derivatives exist.) But the expression “infinitely differentiable at a point” is still a well-defined expression.

Comment: Hmm, never heard of that expression. But if you say so, I believe you. :o)

Comment: @amsmath See here: https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Infinitely_differentiable_function

Comment: It does not follow that they need be smooth in a neighborhood simultaneously.  So, do you want to assume that the $f$ are continuous, measurable, AC, smooth, etc.?  The weight of the related function space is relevant.

Comment: @JohnSamples All I want is for $f^{(n)}(0)$ to exist for all $n$.

Comment: I suspect that a maximal chain in $X$ is countably saturated.  Assuming CH this would uniquely determine it up to isomorphism.  Without CH I would guess that there can probably be non-isomorphic maximal chains.

Comment: My impression also is that there are non-isomorphic ones.  A Cantor Set can obviously be constructed by restricting to the locally PL maps, trying to get something more exotic now.

Comment: Oh wait, isn't $f(x)=x^2$ obviously a maximal element of $X$? So, I think you will only get saturation if you restrict to $f$ such that $f^{(n)}=0$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I will write $\prec$ for your $\preceq$, since this relation is a strict order.]

Let $Y$ consist of all $f\in X$ such that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n$.  Then $Y$ has the following saturation property:

> Let $A,B\subset Y$ be two countable chains such that $a\prec b$ for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.  Then there exists $c\in Y$ such that $a\prec c\prec b$ for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.

I do not have the fortitude to write out the proof; it is a messy but essentially straightforward diagonalization.  We have countably many constraints in constructing $c$ (for each $a\in A$ and each $n$ we must eventually have $c>na$, for each $b\in B$ and each $n$ we must eventually have $c<b/n$, and for each $n$ and $m$ we must eventually have $|c^{(n)}|<1/m$).  We construct $c$ bit by bit as we approach $0$ from the right (or the left), and on each bit we add one new constraint that we are required to satisfy.  Since there are countably many constraints, we can arrange that every constraint eventually gets added and so each constraint is satisfied in some neighborhood of $0$.

Now let us turn back to $X$.  For $f\in X$, let $d(f)$ be the least $n$ such that $f^{(n)}(0)\neq 0$ (if no such $n$ exists, i.e. if $f\in Y$, we write $d(f)=\infty$).  Since we require $f(x)>0$ for $x>0$, $d(f)$ must be even if it is finite.  Moreover, observe that if $d(f)$ is finite, then for all $g$, $g\prec f$ iff $d(g)>d(f)$ (this is immediate from considering the degree $d(f)$ Taylor expansions with remainder of $f$ and $g$).

It follows that if $C\subset X$ is a maximal chain, then for each even positive integer $n$, $C$ contains exactly one element $f_n$ such that $d(f_n)=n$.  So, $C$ has order-type $D+\omega^*$, where $D=C\cap Y$ is a maximal chain in $Y$.

By the saturation property of $Y$ above, $D$ must be countably saturated: for any countable $A,B\subseteq D$ with $a\prec b$ for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, there exists $c\in D$ such that $a\prec c\prec b$.  So this says $D$ is fundamentally "uncountable" in a much stronger sense than any of the chains you mentioned: it is "uncountably dense".  Not only is it a dense linear order, but every element must have uncountable cofinality from both sides.  No element of $D$ can be approached above or below by a countable sequence, since you can always squeeze another element in between.

Assuming the continuum hypothesis, a back-and-forth argument shows that there is a unique countably saturated linear order of cardinality $\aleph_1=2^{\aleph_0}$ up to isomorphism.  So in that case, $D$ is unique up to isomorphism and thus so is $C\cong D+\omega^*$.

In the absence of the continuum hypothesis, $D$ (and hence $C$) may not be unique up to isomorphism.  In particular, it is consistent with ZFC for there to exist maximal chains $D,D'\subset Y$ which have different lower cofinalities (where by lower cofinality I mean the minimal cardinality of a subset that is unbounded below).  This follows from a theorem of Hechler (described [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/29626/75)); Hechler's theorem is about sequences of natural numbers but such a sequence $(a_n)$ can be turned into one of your smooth functions by taking $f(1/n)=1/a_n!$ for each $n$ and picking a nice smooth interpolation in between.

Comment: A few questions. First of all, are you saying that there is no function $f\in X$ for which $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^n}{f}=0$ for all $n$? Can you prove that?  Second of all, can you explain what “every element must have uncountable cofinality from both sides” means?

Comment: Also, is there any way I can get a feel for what $D$ looks like?  Like is it possible to construct a set isomorphic to $D$ whose elements aren’t functions, but numbers or something?  And what is the largest ordinal (largest well-ordered set) embeddable in $D$?

Comment: There is no $f\in X$ such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^2}{f}=0$!  Just write $f(x)=\frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2+g(x)$ where $g(x)=o(x^2)$ as $x\to 0$ by the Taylor series with remainder.  The limit is then $2/f''(0)$, which cannot be $0$.

Comment: The cofinality of $d\in D$ from the left is the smallest length of an increasing well-ordered sequence which converges to $d$, and the cofinality from the right is the same but for decreasing sequences.  So to say $d$ has uncountable cofinality from both sides means that $d$ cannot be approached by a countable sequence.

Comment: There is definitely no concrete way to get a feel for $D$.  This is a highly pathological and really complicated structure.  If you want to get intuition for it, you should think about what the countable saturation property means.  There is probably no largest ordinal that embeds in $D$ and the largest regular cardinal that embeds in $D$ is independent of ZFC.

Comment: If you are familiar with surreal numbers, then assuming the continuum hypothesis, $D$ is isomorphic to the set of surreal numbers of birthday $<\omega_1$.  (This isomorphism is highly non-canonical though.)

Comment: OK thanks, the set of surreal numbers whose birthdays are countable ordinals gives me a feel for what $D$ looks like.

Comment: I think this MathOverflow post answers which ordinals are embeddable in $D$: https://mathoverflow.net/a/226399/5017 But I don’t know what the superscript + notation means.  Do you?

Comment: $\lambda^+$ just means the cardinal that comes after $\lambda$.  So yes, assuming the continuum hypothesis, the ordinals that embed in $D$ are all ordinals less than $(\omega_1)^+=\omega_2$.  Without the continuum hypothesis things get much hairier though.